# Contenteditable paragraph tag on enter

Tags: html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I was wondering if there is an acceptable way to force all major browsers to insert paragraph tag instead of the default tag that they insert on pressing enter key when contentEditable is true.

As far as I know IE inserts p automatically. But Google Chrome inserts div tag and Firefox inserts br (WTF?!).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it just absurd that only Internet Explorer makes sense out of the browsers you mentioned? By the way, Chrome creates new paragraphs when you press Enter within another paragraph.

Comment: This is a great question! Something i don't understand at all is why browsers implement <br> so differently. Certainly from a conceptual point of view <br> and <p> have very different meaning (example explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13688203/3051627 ). Surely with the drive to web standards it's not too much to ask that browsers implement this consistently.

Answer (score 19):

you can use `document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');` in event like `keypress` or `keydown`, etc. to use paragraphs after enter press. For example:

```
element.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == '13')
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
}, false);
```

Comment: I can't speak for all browsers but firefox does indeed wrap the text in p on pressing Enter ....the problem is it also auto inserts <br></br> resulting in somthing like as follows: <p>my text<br></br></p>  ... which seems very strange handling to me.

Comment: formatBlock reformats everything. So if you have an h1 there, it'll get turned into a paragraph tag

Answer (score 0):

As its build in the browser you can't change that behaviour. You could work around by detecting browser and replacing elements correspondingly. Very ugly, I know.

Also check WhatWG for background: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031577.html

Comment: **Your link is down**. What's why I constantly repeat: *Don't* paste plain links to websites, take some effort in providing a self-explanatiry answer. Than add plausible links as *bonus*.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found the solution (CHROME, MSIE, FIREFOX), follow my code in the link.

```
$(document).on('click','#myButton',function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
        var str = $('#myDiv').html().replace(/<br>/gi,'').replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,'');
    else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1)
        var str = $('#myDiv').html().replace(/<\/br>/gi,'').replace(/<br>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/br>/gi,'');
    else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") == -1)
        var str = $('#myDiv').html().replace(/<br>/gi,'').replace(/<p>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/p>/gi,'');    
    $('#myDiv2').removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible').text(str);
    $('#myDiv3').removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible').html(str);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kzkxo70L/1/